# Error while building Spark-jobserver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

unresolved dependency: com.ning#async-http-client;1.8.10: org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;9!oss-parent.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:

```
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1442)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this would some sort of corrupted Ivy 2 cache issue, deleting the ~/.ivy2/ directory entirely and relaunching SBT resolved the problem.